# How to show columns that have more than x non empty rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table and I would like to see only the columns that have more than x non empty rows(months).

[image]

For example, I want to see only columns which have more than 4 non empty rows.

Hence, columns **70672**, **1014006** and **1014015** should not be visible.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a helper column to your original data, you could do something like:

`=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$193,">0",$B$2:$B$193,B2)>4`

[image]

And then use it as a filter in your pivot table:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. For example, in column A, there might be more than one times data for Oct-18 and 1014000. 

In the end, I want to only see the REF that have data in more than x different months